# Difference between Deployment Groups and Environments in Azure DevOps Services\Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

In Azure Pipelines, we have Deployment Groups & Environments as separate options but are they both not suppose to add a list of server belonging to an environment as a group. 
Clarification on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

> Difference between Deployment Groups and Environments in Azure DevOps Services\Server

In simple terms, [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) is that:

> A deployment group is a logical set of **deployment target machines that
>   have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the
>   physical environments**; for example, "Dev", "Test", "UAT", and
>   "Production". In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping
>   of agents, much like an agent pool.

And [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) is that:

> Environment represents **a collection of resources** such as namespaces
>   within Kubernetes clusters, Azure Web Apps, virtual machines,
>   databases, which can be targeted by deployments from a pipeline.

**Personal Opinion:**

They both have the same theory in actual deployment. But, **since Deployment group jobs are not yet supported in YAML.** In this case, the Environments comes up. As you can get following state from the document:

> **While environment at its core is a grouping of resources, the
>   resources themselves represent actual deployment targets**. The
>   Kubernetes resource and virtual machine resource types are currently
>   supported.

Besides, the environment has a series of advantages:

- Deployment history
- Traceability of commits and work items
- Diagnose resource health
- Permissions

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helpful, but the same documentation you reference notes deployment groups in "Classic", which suggests environments is the way to go. I am still wondering what the underlying technical implications are when it comes to internally hosted shared (2+ app or db) VMs. If you've any insight on that it would be helpful.

Comment: Good summary. I'll add that it seems like Environments can't be registered as easily as deployment groups right now. For dep. groups there are 3 install methods one of them being an extension in Azure. Registering environments seems to require manually running install command on the VMs, and the command is _copied_ from the DevOps UI.

Comment: Environments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops

Deployment Groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 2):

A deployment group is basically a set of deployment target machines or physical environments, which are machines in which an agent is installed.

Environments are a group of resources  like Azure Web Apps, virtual machines, databases etc.. which targets a deployment

both can have different groups for Dev, Test, UAT, and Production

Answer (score 0):

Both helps us to connect with deployment target server. Deployment group is for classic pipeline and Environments is for YAML pipeline.

Comment: Please try to post answers that add new information.

Answer (score 0):

Each environment creates an implicit deployment group Environment-{EnvironmentID}-{Guid}.

Unfortunately from the environment UI you cannot see the status of the resources which is extremely annoying, you also cannot see the tags without click on each resource and choosing manage tags. The UI for environments is extremely basic.